# Cannot install roxygen2 on Debian Jessie

Tags: r, linux, installation, roxygen2

When I try to install `roxygen2` I get:

```
> sudo Rscript -e 'install.packages("roxygen2", repos="http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/")'         
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/src/contrib/roxygen2_5.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'text/plain' length 106197 bytes (103 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 103 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘roxygen2’ ...
** package ‘roxygen2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c isComplete.cpp -o isComplete.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c leadingSpaces.cpp -o leadingSpaces.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c parser2.cpp -o parser2.o
parser2.cpp: In function ‘Rcpp::CharacterVector find_includes(std::string)’:
parser2.cpp:165:35: error: too many arguments to function ‘void Rcpp::stop(const string&)’
     stop("Failed to open %s", path);
                                   ^
In file included from /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:131:0,
                 from /usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from parser2.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/exceptions.h:195:17: note: declared here
     inline void stop(const std::string& message) {
                 ^
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:137: recipe for target 'parser2.o' failed
make: *** [parser2.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘roxygen2’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/roxygen2’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpSn8jzt/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("roxygen2", repos = "http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/") :
  installation of package ‘roxygen2’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried several different repos, but result is always the same. Is it a problem with version that got published in repos? What else could I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadley noticed this problem with other packages and stated on a Github thread that the solution is to use the dev verstion of `Rcpp`, i.e.

```
install_github("RcppCore/Rcpp")
```

So, upgrade `Rcpp` then fully shutdown all RStudio and R processes, then restart and reinstall `roxygen2`.

Comment: I don't think that answer is correct.  The CRAN version of Rcpp should be just fine: I use both released versions of roxygen2 and Rcpp on several machines at home and work, they go into Rocker containers for Docker etc pp.  Then again, I mostly use Debian "testing" rather than stable.  The most likely culprit may be an older distro version of `r-cran-rcpp` on that machine.  So just add Rcpp from CRAN and you're good.   FWIW, I *essentially never* recommend `install_github()` as we have proper release procedures for Rcpp.  Getting random snapshots from GitHub is much more random.